Google Identity Platform OIDC SSO setup with 3rd party apps
We are required to connect the Google Identity Platform via OIDC with our two 3rd party web apps. When the user attempts to log in via 3rd party app then the user should be redirected to a custom login page that looks like the attached screenshot. Users can authenticate via email/password or sign in via common providers once authenticated the user should be redirected back to the 3rd party app. 
I have configured providers[screenshot attached] but am stuck on what URLs to provide in 3rd party app OIDC setup page. 
Is this flow possible with Google Identity Platform and OIDC? Any help regarding OIDC URL setup or related resources will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
